# Ubuntu 18.04 libosmesa6 depends libglapi-mesa (= 18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1) but 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 is to be installed

Tags: dependencies, package, version, ubuntu-18.04

Quite a few people encounter this issue, especially those who want to use Gym and Mujoco for reinforcement learning. The installation process is frustrating, but luckily [some people](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667416/how-can-i-safely-revert-libglapi-mesa-version) spot part of the issue

I want to post this problem, so hopefully the Ubuntu developers could see, as the [instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068937/how-can-i-submit-a-bug-report-on-18-04-update) doesn't lead me to any dialog box to write something.

The problem is happened as followed:

1. I want to use Mujoco, so I follow the installation instruction, but when I implement import mujoco_py in python3.5/3.6, it gives the following error:

   `>>> import mujoco_py`

   `Import error. Trying to rebuild mujoco_py.`

   `running build_ext`
   `building 'mujoco_py.cymj' extension`

   ...

   `/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mujoco_py/gl/osmesashim.c:1:10: fatal error: GL/osmesa.h: No such file or directory`
    `#include <GL/osmesa.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~`
2. [Quite a few people](https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/issues/96) suggest to install libosmesa-dev by running sudo apt-get install libosmesa6-dev, so I tried it. But the error is:

   `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libosmesa6-dev : Depends: libosmesa6 (= 18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
3. Then I think this sudo apt-get install libosmesa6 would solve it, but unfortunately:

   `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libosmesa6 : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1) but 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 is to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
4. It looks like it's the **version** of current **libglapi-mesa** (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1) is incompatible with what mesa really needs(18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1)
5. I am confused about how to downgrade it, because it seems like there are tons of packages depending on the current version of libglapi-mesa. For example, when I tried to correct the version, using sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa=18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1 , the warning is going crazy:

   `The following additional packages will be installed:
   policykit-1-gnome
   The following packages will be REMOVED:
   apturl cheese deja-dup gdm3 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-2
   gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-calendar
   gnome-control-center gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-initial-setup
   gnome-online-accounts gnome-session-bin gnome-shell
   gnome-startup-applications gnome-todo gnome-user-docs gnome-user-guide
   gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-vaapi gvfs
   gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8
   libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
   libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libgl1
   libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglx-mesa0 libglx0 libgoa-backend-1.0-1
   libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libmutter-2-0 libtotem0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
   libyelp0 mutter nautilus nautilus-share rhythmbox-plugins shotwell totem
   totem-plugins ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
   ubuntu-session update-manager update-notifier x11-utils xorg
   xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
   xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom
   xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati
   xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel
   xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl
   xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa
   xserver-xorg-video-vmware xwayland yelp zenity`
6. Now when I looked back to the Ubuntu 18.04 USB installation driver, I noticed that the version of current libglapi-mesa (**18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1**) is already there (**pre-installed**) on this Ubuntu 18.04 version. I am a newbie to Ubuntu, I already reinstall the system for few times due to following different people's post. I really hope Ubuntu team or MESA team could fix this issue soon.
   If you know how to solve this (other than install Ubuntu 14/16), please leave your comment, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very new to Ubuntu, knowing nothing about it, so my question looks a bit dump. But here is how I solved it for my situation when I could not proper install libosmesa6-dev due to package dependency:

1 Try to google `libosmesa6=18.0.5-rc5-0ubuntu0`, download the deb file for your Ubuntu version, and cpu architecture(e.g. my case 0ubuntu0~18.04.1 (amd64 binary)), and install it manually. This is because in the current package repository, there is no `libsomesa6=18.0.5-rc5-0ubuntu0` to match `libglapi-mesa=18.0.5...`

2 Now, I add repository for newer version of libosmesa6-dev to my repository, and install it with apt-get command:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install libosmesa6-dev`

After this, the libosmesa6-dev, libosmesa6, libglapi-mesa would be automatically upgraded to a newer version.

3 Once it's installed, I have no issue to import mujoco_py under my environment